# Yes/No field(access) in dropdownlist shows as true/false instead of 0/1 as per db

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, ms-access, ms-access-2003

Dropdownlist is driven by the accessdatasource, the `[Being Used]` field is an `Yes/No` data type in access and it takes `0/1` as input but the dropdownlist shows the values as `True/False` instead of `0/1` or `Yes/No`. So when I select fasle/true I get a data type mismatch error, how to fix this? Any help is appreciated!!

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList5" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True" AutoPostBack="True" CausesValidation="True" DataSourceID="AccessDataSource6" DataTextField="Being Used in Target" DataValueField="Being Used" EnableViewState="True">    
<asp:ListItem Selected="True" Text="Select Being Used or not" Value= '2' ></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>

           <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" 
           ControlToValidate="DropDownList5"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

        <asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource6" runat="server" DataFile="~/App_Data/SimSEAT.mdb"
            SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT test.[Being Used] FROM `test` WHERE 
            ((Labs.[Lab Name])= [WhichLabName] OR [WhichLabName] = '0') AND
            (((Labs.[Target])= [WhichTarget] OR [WhichTarget] = '0')  
             )">

        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList3" Name="Lab Name"   PropertyName="SelectedValue"/>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList4" Name="Target"   PropertyName="SelectedValue" />

            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:AccessDataSource>
```

Comment: The Access Yes/No is -1/0, True/False, but that is the value True or False, not a text data type

Comment: but where did I use it as a text?

Comment: are you saying it will throw error since I am using true or false instead of values? if so I know the reason behind the error but why the dropdownlist is getting true/false instead of 1/0 ?